# Работа и полносвязное взаимодействие анотаций и их анализаторов

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Я много гуглил и смотрел уроки по объяснению аннотаций, но не понял как именно можно создать свою аннотацию. Точнее не как создать, а как сделать так, что бы она заработала.

Я знаю как их объявлять через @interface, и @Retention @Target, понимаю что у них могут быть поля и методы без тела, но вот что дальше?

Как я понял, что бы аннотация работала, у нее должен быть считыватель, в роли которого выступает класс анализатор анотаций. И если я прав, тогда здесь самая загвоздка. 
Как я понял аннотируемый класс в первую очередь обращается к самой анотации, но ведь в ней кроме как полей и абстрактных методов ничего нет.

У меня два вопроса:Как в итоге связать анотируемый класс с классом анализатором? И как в классе анализаторе описать логику самой аннотации? 
Может кто нибудь объяснить на пальцах и желательно с простым примером кода.

P.S.  Вопрос рефлексии так же изучил и проработал, но мне это не дало особого понимания в самой работе и структуре аннотаций.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Анализаторы работают с уже готовыми аннотациями, а не кастомными. Например, IntellijIdea code analysis понимает @NotNull из пакета org.jetbrains.annotations https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

Comment: Значит я ошибаюсь. В любом случае, где и как тогда описывается сама логика работы аннотаций, ведь в них самих по сути ничего нет.

Comment: @Андрей все верно, аннотации - это **исключительно** метаданные, как вы их будете обрабатывать - зависит уже от вас и ваших обработчиков. Никакой "магии" на самом деле нет, просто некоторые обработчики сканируют все классы и находят нужные реализации, либо вызов этих обработчиков спрятан где-то внутри фреймворка.

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация это по сути метка как пустой интерфейс Serializable(Он просто указывает что класс можно сериализовать). У аннотации нет какого то исполняемого тела. Фреймворки типа spring и hibernate, либо ваш самописный фреймворк анализируют ваши классы и проверяют есть ли у класса аннотация. Например если есть аннотоация @Entity указывающая что класс является сущностью hibernate, аннотация @Table(name = "metal") указывает, что сущность мапится на таблицу metal. Что бы это понять фреймворк при анализе классов делает что то вроде:

```
String tableName;
Class aClass= Metal.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof Table){
        Table myAnnotation = (Table) annotation;
        tableName = myAnnotation.name();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот я с точки пустого интерфейса его в целом и рассматриваю. Например Test JUnit. Когда мы тестируем какой-либо метод, мы над ним ставим аннотацию соответствующюю. Но больше мы ничего не пишем, ни методов, ни анализаторов, ничего. Как IDEA запускает этот метод, ведь по сути это обычный маркер метода, и при обращении к самой анотации в ней кроме как этап исполнения и таргет исполнения ничего не написанно. По логике в ЮНИТЕ должен быт класс, который проверяет есть ли анотация, и как-то его запускает. Вот и как происходит обращение к этому классу, если я ничего кроме аннотацииTest не прописываю

Comment: @Андрей Есть класс, который проверяет есть ли аннотация у метода, и если да - то запускает метод. https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/TestClass.java тут небольшой пример, как оно это делает.